# How do I filter db.table by another another column from another table in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get a list of new potential borrowers that are not existing borrowers. I have two tables in my MVC application that are mapped using EF 5. Both tables have a field named client_Name;

```
var existingBorrower = from s in db.ExistingBorrower select s.client_Name;
```

i can confirm that existingBorrower.ToList() returns a list of items with the existing borrowers.

I can't get the code below to work. I am trying to exclude the list of existingborrowers not just one item.

```
var newBorrowers = db.AllClients.Where(x => !x.CLIENT_NAME.Contains(existingClients.AsEnumerable()));
```

Comment: Does the Existing Borrower table have a numeric primary key, like ID?

Comment: it does. It has both Name and ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing both tables have a key of the client called 'ID' which is unique and has the same value for one client in the two tables, or it may be primary key in one table and foreign key in the second table:

```
var existingIds = db.ExistingBorrower.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();

var newBorrowers = db.AllClients.Where(x => !existingIds.Contains(x.ID));
```

This query will translate in SQL to condition

```
WHERE ID NOT IN (val1, val2 ,val3, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use your first query to get a list and compare that

```
List<string> existingBorrowers = (from s in db.ExistingBorrower 
                                  select s.client_Name).ToList();

List<string> newBorrowers = (from a in db.AllClients 
                             where !existingBorrowers.Contains(a.client_Name)
                             select a.client_Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to get the list of new borrower

```
var existingBorrowers = existingBorrower.ToList();
var newBorrowers = db.AllClients.Where(x => existingBorrowers.All(n => n != x)).ToList();
```

Comment: I think creating list of id's and checking that client id not in this list (using `Contains`) will be more efficient and will translate in single sql request. And you won't have to store all borrowers in memory, only id's.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one query:

```
var existingBorrowers = db.AllClients
                          .Where(clnt => !db.ExistingBorrower
                                         .Any(eb => eb.client_Name == clnt.CLIENT_NAME));
```

So you're looking for clients of which the name doesn't exist as ExistingBorrower. I assume that `client_Name` uniquely identifies a client (that's absolutely required to make this work correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can perform an outer join and get only the non matching records like

```
var existingBorrower = from s in db.ExistingBorrower select s.client_Name;

var newBorrowers = db.AllClients
                   .GroupJoin(existingBorrower.ToList(), 
                              i => i.CLIENT_NAME, 
                              o => o.CLIENT_NAME,
                              (allClient, brrower) => new {allClient, brrower})
                   .SelectMany(z => z.brrower.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                      (x, y) => new
                        {
                            ClientName = x.allClient.CLIENT_NAME,
                            Brrower = y

                        }).Where(b => b.Brrower == null);
```